# Removing duplicates from the List-LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a situation Where I need to remove the duplicates from the list. This is coming because I have combined some lists togather.

```
List<Guid> CompleteListOfPeople = firstListGuids.Union(secondListGuids).ToList().Union(thirdListGuids).ToList();
```

What should I do to filer the list of Guids so that I get only unique Guids?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Union` should already give you unique values. Note that you don't need the intermediate `ToList()` call. Just:

```
List<Guid> completeListOfPeople = firstListGuids.Union(secondListGuids).
                                                .Union(thirdListGuids)
                                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I did not knew using Union will get rid of duplicates. Thank you.